# Exponential Growth Functions

Tags: functions

I have a worksheet of about 24 problems and it seems to be split by two different sorts. I'm wondering if one could walk me through two so I can finish the worksheet on my own.

```
Write the exponential function y=20e^-0.04t in the form y=ab^t.  

Find b accurate to 5 decimal places.
```

The second type of questions on the worksheet is in the following format.

```
Write the exponential function P=721(0.98)^t in the form P=ae^kt .
```

Thank you in advance to anyone that can point me in the right direction

Comment: $$\large (a^b)^c=a^{(b\cdot c)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one thing you should know to do your homework and it is the following formula
$$
e^{a\cdot\ln b} = b^a.
$$
For example, if you have to write function $P = (0.555)^t$ in the form $P = e^{kt}$, then directly from the above formula you will get
$$
(0.555)^t = e^{t\cdot \ln(0.555)}.
$$
P.S. If you need to find $e^x$ with some accuracy, then it would be useful to represent $e^x$ as a series.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me finish the homework

Answer (score 0):

$$
y=20e^{-0.04t} = 20 {\huge(}e^{-0.04}{\huge)}^t = ab^t\qquad\text{where }a=20\text{ and }b= e^{-0.04}.
$$

(For your second question, the answer written by Ivan Polekhin suffices.)